# Create a DNS NSRecord in C#

Tags: c#, dns

I try to create a DNS NSRecord by [DNS WMI Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
The below is my sample code.

How can I set an IP address for a NSRecord? I know Enter the IP is required for a NSRecord.

```
    ManagementScope WmiScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + System.Environment.MachineName + "\\ROOT\\MicrosoftDNS");
ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath("MicrosoftDNS_NSType");
ManagementClass zone = new ManagementClass(WmiScope, path, null);
ManagementBaseObject p = zone.GetMethodParameters("CreateInstanceFromPropertyData");


p.Properties["DnsServerName"].Value = WmiScope.Path.Server;
p.Properties["ContainerName"].Value = "mydomain.com";
p.Properties["OwnerName"].Value = "";
p.Properties["NSHost"].Value = "ns1.domain.com";
zone.InvokeMethod("CreateInstanceFromPropertyData", p, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically an NS record for a domain does not contain an IP address, it is the authroitative record telling "anybody" requesting the NS record, all of the NS records for the domain.

`An NS-record identifies the name of a DNS server - not the IP-address.`

http://www.mtgsy.net/dns/record_ns.htm

Comment: When I want to add a NSRecord to Microsoft DNS server. Adding IP address id required. Please visit this screenshot http://s1.picofile.com/file/7244522361/dns.jpg

Comment: The IPAddress in that case is only required to verify that the nameserver exists, when it is persisted in DNS, the IP address is not saved. Once you enter the hostname and click resolve, it will show the IP Address in the Name Server tab, but if you were to ever update those records, it should resolve the IP addresses again on dialog open.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but I am wrestling with this issue, maybe this will help someone.

While the IPAddress for the NSRecord is not required, Microsoft DNS will in fact create a host (A) glue record for that NSRecord.  By having a glue record in the delegated zone, a step is saved (slightly quicker) in not having to look up the address of that NSRecord.

Sadly, having wasted a couple of hours now, there seems to be no method for adding a glue record using WMI.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is a very old post (4+ years old), but there is a way to add IP addresses for nameservers with WMI. As JayRO-GreyBeard above me states, you'll need to add a glue record for each nameserver.

A glue record is a Resource Record, and you can add it with 'CreateInstanceFromTextRepresentation' (the management path is 'MicrosoftDNS_ResourceRecord').

The 'TextRepresentation' you need to use for a glue record is '{hostname} IN A {IP}'. For example: 'ns1.example.com. IN A 127.0.0.1'. As the example show, make sure you end the hostname with a dot ('.').

```
ManagementClass objMC_RRecords = new ManagementClass(objScope, new ManagementPath("MicrosoftDNS_ResourceRecord"), null);

ManagementBaseObject objParams_RR_NS1 = objMC_RRecords.GetMethodParameters("CreateInstanceFromTextRepresentation");
objParams_RR_NS1["DnsServerName"] = null;
objParams_RR_NS1["ContainerName"] = "example.com";
objParams_RR_NS1["TextRepresentation"] = "ns1.example.com. IN A 127.0.0.1";

objMC_RRecords.InvokeMethod("CreateInstanceFromTextRepresentation", objParams_RR_NS1, null);
```

More info on the 'CreateInstanceFromTextRepresentation' method can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682714(v=vs.85).aspx